# Display mysql query string into tabular form

Tags: php

Not sure how to do this. The code below does not work.

From the function `getRecords()`

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM partners'); 
return $result;
```

And this where I want to display

```
<?php $records = getRecords(); ?>
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Partner name</td>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td colspan="2">Actions</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            if (isset($records)) {
                foreach ($records as $record) {
                    $row = '<tr>'
                        . '<td>' . $record['partner']. '</td>'
                        . '<td>' . $record['username']. '</td>'
                        . '<td>' . $record['password']. '</td>'
                        . '</tr>';
                    echo $row;
                }
            }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I hope you get the idea. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the part of your question where you tell us what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getRecords() {
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM partners'); 
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $records = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $records[] = $row;
    }
    return $records;
}
```

Comment: Figures, pick the spoonfeed option and don't go to read the manual or turn on error reporting. This is why spoonfeeding is bad.

Comment: @Tomalak Sure you are a professional and I'm a noob with a deadline to beat. Sorry for using spoonfeed option mr pro.

Comment: @Turtel: Just means you'll run right up to the _next_ deadline, too. And the one after that, and the one after that... I'm not a pro because I was magically born with a MySQL reference in my head; I'm a pro because I know how to prioritise my own advancement and education.

Comment: @Tomalak

"Just means you'll run right up to the next deadline, too. And the one after that, and the one after that..." - Sure, this happens to anyone.

"I'm not a pro because I was magically born with a MySQL reference in my head; I'm a pro because I know how to prioritise my own advancement and education." - What's your point?

I just needed a quick solution since the deadline was minutes away.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($records as ($record) {
```

This contains an obvious syntax error, and it's also not how you iterate MySQL resultsets.

You have three actions to take here:

1. Turn on error reporting;
2. Fix trivial typos;
3. Read the documentation for the MySQL API in PHP.